# Autostart PtokaX at boot only after mysqld has started

Tags: linux, boot, debian, mysql

I've the following script in `/etc/init.d/server.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             PtokaX server
# Short-Description:    PtokaX P2P server
### END INIT INFO

/home/serve/PtokaX/PtokaX -d -c /home/serve/PtokaX
```

where `-d` is for starting as daemon and `-c` specifies the location of configuration files.

The scripts I have in PtokaX connect to MySQL server and the PtokaX server starts before MySQL server has started. This causes PtokaX scripts to raise errors and several of the features on hub fail.

Can I update the script in some way so that it'll start only if MySQL daemon has started?

Comment: That's a truly terrible init.d script. It forces the Bourne Again shell when it doesn't actually need it; and it doesn't implement the conventional start and stop verbs. [This one](http://forum.ptokax.org/index.php?topic=8059.5;wap2) is little better, though. If you want simple files with a straightforward dependency system I suggest looking at `systemd`, where [a ptokax "service unit file" will look like this](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/home:HighwayStar:sandbox:p2p/ptokax/ptokax.service). Then forget hand-rolling your own complex buggy init.d scripts entirely.

Comment: @JdeBP I previously had the script written with `case start-stop-*` statements, but the server wasn't even starting at that time. I changed it to simply execute the command as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename the rc-script to `ptokax` (the name `server.sh` is just lame as it conveys no information to the user).

Then try changing the LSB header in that file to

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ptokax
# Required-Start:    $network mysql
# Required-Stop:     $network mysql
# Should-Start:      $time
# Should-Stop:       $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the PtokaX DC daemon
# Description:       Controls the PtokaX DC server daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

And then run

```
# insserv ptokax
```

to make the [`insserv`](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot) know about your service and rebuild its dependency maps.

I beleive that these days the old-ish

```
# update-rc.d ptokax defaults
```

should also trigger `insserv` but I don't know for sure.

See also [this](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) about the meaning of the LSB header fields.  Note that you might also want to start-depend on other virtual facilities such as `$remote_fs`, `$named` and `$syslog`—depending on which of them PtokaX relies on.

Comment: Let's say if I want `apache2` to be started as well, would I use `$network apache2 mysql` or `$network apache2 $network mysql`?

Comment: @hjpotter92, doesn't matter--this only states the listed facilities have to be started by the time your service starts. The order in which they do so is undefined (at least you can't affect it in the LSB header of your service, which is sensible).

Comment: @hjpotter92, ah, I misread the question. No, `$network` is a so-called "virtual facility" (hence the `$` in the name)--it does not have a particular service behind itself or might be provided by various service (like `$named` does, for instance). So no, it's not a prefix for "mysql"--they both are facilities, just one is virtual and another one is real. Please read the fscking docs--I've provided the relevant pointers.